# JPA Hibernate cast to non Entity class

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a big database and I need to make a query that join with, at least, 3 tables. The problem is that the resultset from this query isn't an Entity class.

The query:

```
SELECT avg(g.grade) avgGrade, max(g.grade) maxGrade, min(g.grade) minGrade FROM...
```

The new class:

```java
class Stat {
  float avgGrade;
  float maxGrade;
  float minGrade;

  // constructor + getters and setters
}
```

Now I need to get that three values from the query. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices (I think there is more but these two should be the most common one), first using the way Nayan Wadekar suggest, which construct the data object by constructor.

The second one is just select the fields you want, and Hibernate is going to return you a list of tuples.  Each element of the list is an Object[], which represents one "row" of result.  You can self-implement the transformation from tuple to your Stat class.

Comment: can i use entitymanager or i must use hibernate session object ?

Comment: I believe it works with JPA EM too (I haven't tried out to prove it, just by my bare memory)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below query using Constructor Expression, modify it accordingly.

> SELECT NEW package_name.Stat(avg(g.grade), max(g.grade), min(g.grade))
>   FROM ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the class Stat has an appropriate constructor

```
select new your_pkg_name.Stat(avg(g.grade) as avgGrade, max(g.grade)  as maxGrade, min(g.grade) as minGrade) FROM ...
```

Comment: And then how do I do to get the object? I have to make a cast?

    Stat stat = (Stat) em.createQuery(hql).getSingleResult();

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the avg(g.grade) returns a double and my class Stat's constructor accept a float, so I have an error related to not found constructor exception.

Thanks to all :)